# Can I create a Photoshop droplet to resize a batch of images, both portrait and landscape, to the same size?

Tags: photoshop

I want a Photoshop droplet that can resize several images to the same target size.

Of course I can put landscape and portrait images into separate folders and apply a different action on each, but that is so lame.

So I made a script like this:

```
if (app.activeDocument.width.value > app.activeDocument.height.value) {
    app.activeDocument.resizeImage("920 px", undefined, undefined,
                                   ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
} else {
    app.activeDocument.resizeImage("455 px", undefined, undefined,
                                   ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
}
```

Which works fine. But the problem is that I need a different script for each different resolution. This could also be solved using the Save for Web command, but I believe that behaves the same way as resizing.

I can ask the user to specify a width inside the script (using a dialog box) but I imagine if I do this inside a droplet, and I drop several files over the droplet, it will show the dialog box for every file. I want to show it only once.

So my question is: is there a better way to create a universal resizing droplet that can ask the desired width/height once for every batch? Or is the only way to create several scripts and droplets, one for each resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I have an action for resizing my images, where I specify the size in percent instead of pixels. That way the action works for both vertical and horizontal images.

Comment: i could do that changing the dpi. but since i crop some photos the original size is not uniform, so i can't do it this way :(